# Can't open file from path using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to write the code for a mediaplayer using PyQt5. I have followed many tutorials but I can't figure out how to open the file from the local path on my computer.
My script, by now, downloads some videos from a website and then saves it into my computer. After that I can see a list with the different videos I've downloaded and I want to select one and use the path to open it. The problem is here:

```
    def openVideo(self, videoPath):
    if videoPath != '':
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl(videoPath).path()))
        self.playButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
```

QUrl can't read str type variables, and videoPath is a string that contains the path to the video I have selected.

Comment: QUrl *does* read strings, what matters is the *content* of the string, but since you're not giving us an example of those paths, it's impossible to help you. Also, you should not use `path()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QUrl::fromLocalFile`

```
self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile(videoPath).path()))
```

Documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QUrl.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described what error the interpreter is outputting. For all we know, videoPath could indeed equal `''`!

Assuming that the error is what you described, have you tried to use `QUrl::fromLocalFile`?

[From the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QUrl.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile):

> Returns a QUrl representation of localFile, interpreted as a local file. This function accepts paths separated by slashes as well as the native separator for this platform.